# How to ignore tab spaces in eclipse cvs file compare?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to compare two files from different branches but there is a lot of differences due to tab characters in one file. How can I tell eclipse cvs plugin that ignore the tab spaces when doing the comparison?

Answer (score 40):

There should be a setting to ignore whitespace, which includes tabs.  Go to Preferences and then search for Compare.  There should be a setting to ignore whitespace.

It will be in Preferences->General->Compare/Patch. Check the "Ignore White space" option.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the file and just  select `Ignore White space` .

Comment: Just to clarify, this option is perfect for temporary use. See @atrain's answer to make it permanent.